# Hotkey for line highlight expansions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, resharper, hotkeys

I have lost a good old hotkey when switching to from VS13 to VS15 having Resharper in both.

With the old hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> I could start at `string theHighLightStartsHere = "";` and by pressing my hotkey combination the highlight would expand and also highlight the if, and the next time with highlight would expand to include the try also and so on up the tree.

I have tryed importing my old settings. I have also tryed to choose the same hotkey-scheme that I think I used in VS13, but I might be wrong.

Anyways, what is this feature called and location? So I can rebind my Resharper hotkey, thanks.

```
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        if (true)
        {
            string theHighLightStartsHere = "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `ReSharper_ExtendSelection` and its reverse is `ReSharper_ShrinkSelection`.

You can also reset your keyboard shortcuts to the ReSharper defaults by first going to Visual Studio's Tools → Options → Keyboard and selecting "Reset". This removes all ReSharper shortcuts. Now go to ReSharper → Options → Keyboard & Menus, select the shortcut scheme you want, and hit Apply. This should give you back the defaults.

Comment: I have made a reset and re-choosen the Visual scheme again and rebooted VS15 now with no luck.

In Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard I have "Visual C# 2005" Is that good enough? In the big list I have some Resharper_xx options, but not the RESharper_ExtendSelection, do you know what's wrong? I have bought and installed the lastest Resharper version.
Maybe I can get a clue in my old VS13.

Comment: Did you forget `ReSharper.` prefixed `ReSharper_ExtendSelection`? I found one there.

Comment: Thanks it works great now. I just had to choose text editor and not xaml or global, i was blind. Accepted for sure!